# Is the positive fragment of second-order logic will full semantics compact?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, model-theory, second-order-logic

There are two slightly different versions of compactness:

1. If $\Delta$ is finitely satisfiable, then $\Delta$ is satisfiable.
2. If $\Gamma \models \varphi$ then there exists a finite subset $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0 \models \varphi$.

I'm interested in the second one here because positive second-order logic does not have actual contradictions. For second-order logic though, these two notions line up.

Consider second-order logic with a single non-empty domain. We have function and relation symbols as vocabulary items. A constant is a nullary function.

Additionally, quantifiers can introduce functions and relations of arbitrary arity (e.g. $\exists f / 2$ or $\forall R / 3$). Suppose our connectives are $\land$, $\lor$ and $\lnot$.

Consider the fragment without $\lnot$. Let's call this positive second-order logic.

Positive second-order logic with Henkin semantics is definitely compact.

**I'm wondering whether positive second-order logic with full semantics is compact.**

---

**Attempt:**

One argument for showing that second-order logic with full semantics is not compact is to consider the following statements:

1. for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the domain has at least $n$ entities.
2. the domain is Kuratowski finite (every injection is a bijection).

These are finitely satisfiable but not satisfiable.

However, positive second-order logic is quite weak. It can express *maximum* bounds on the size of the domain, e.g.

$$ \forall x_1 \cdots x_n \mathop. \bigvee_{1 \le i < j \le n+1} x_i = x_j \;\; \text{is equivalent to} \;\; \exists_{\le n} \top $$

It cannot express minimum bounds however.

Additionally, neither Kuratowski finiteness nor Kuratowski-infiniteness can be expressed in positive second-order logic.

We can express that a function is bijective.

$$ \exists g \mathop. \forall x \mathop. x = g(f(x)) \; \text{where $f$ is a free variable} \\ \;\;\; \text{expresses that $f$ is a bijection} $$

I think we can express injectivity as well.

$$ \exists g \mathop. \forall x \mathop. f(x) = f(g(f(x))) \; \text{where $f$ is a free variable} \\ \;\;\; \text{expresses that $f$ is an injection} $$

But we can't form an implication as a single sentence because $\lnot$ and $\to$ are both prohibited.

Comment: I assume the notation in the two definitions of compactness given are standard? If not, maybe it would help to clarify which kinds of entities are represented by each symbol. (To clarify I definitely wouldn't be able to answer this question either way, but it seems interesting and I hope it gets answered.)

Comment: @hasManyStupidQuestions Yes, that notation is standard.

Comment: To clarify then, both $\Delta$ and $\Gamma$/$\Gamma_0$ are to be understood by convention (not just from context) to be models (e.g. as opposed to theories)?

Comment: $\Gamma$, $\Delta$, and $\Delta_0$ are sets of sentences. A sentence is a well-formed formula with no free variables.

Comment: This is a good question; would you be willing to post it to MO (or failing that, would you mind if I did)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I’ll cross-post it later today.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: It is done: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464037/is-the-positive-fragment-of-second-order-logic-compact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compactness does not hold for positive second-order logic with full semantics. Take the language with a single binary relation $\#$ as well as equality $=.$ Take $\Gamma$ to consist of:

- the sentence $\forall x\forall y (x=y\vee x\# y)$ and,
- for each $n\geq 2,$ the sentence $\exists x_1 \dots \exists x_n \bigwedge_{1\leq i<j\leq n} (x_i\#x_j)$ - call this $G_n$

Take $\varphi=\varphi_1\vee\varphi_2$ where:

- $\varphi_1=\exists x\exists y (x=y\wedge x\#y)$
- $\varphi_2=\exists f(f\text{ is injective}\,\wedge\, \exists x\forall y. f(y)\# x).$

Any model $M$ of $\Gamma\cup\{\neg \varphi_1\}$ satisfies ${\#}^M=(\neq)^M$ by which I mean that $\#$ is interpreted as the inequality relation $\{(x,y):x\neq y\}.$ So $M$ is infinite, and it satisfies $\varphi_2$ by taking $f$ to be any injective non-surjective function. Therefore $\Gamma\models\varphi.$

Consider a finite subset $\Gamma_0$ of $\Gamma,$ and set $n=\max\{k:G_k\in\Gamma_0\}.$
Define $M_n$ to be the structure with domain of order $n,$ with ${\#}^{M_n}=({\neq})^{M_n}.$ Then  $M_n$ is a model of $\Gamma_0\cup\{\neg\varphi\}$ so $\Gamma_0\not\models \varphi.$

Comment: Hello Colin, thanks for answering the question. Just so you know, the corresponding MO question is bountied https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464037/is-the-positive-fragment-of-second-order-logic-compact?noredirect=1